# Printing on same line in c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to write the time on the same line instead of it stacking the outputs. I can not seem to get it to work though.

Here is what I have: I thought the `"\r"` would make it reprint on the same line, but this doesn't work. And I also tried `printf("\r");` and that didn't work either.

Can anyone help me figure out how to get this to work?

```
void countdown(int time)
{
    int h = (time / 3600);
    int m = (time / 60) - (h * 60);
    int s = time % 60;

    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << h << ":" << m << ":" << s;
    std::string string = ss.str();

    cout << "\r" << string << endl;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried just cout << h << ":" << m << ":" << s << endl; ?

Comment: You are calling `countdown(...)` multiple times, and want all the times to appear on a single line? Is that the issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rewinding std::cout to go back to the beginning of a line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057977/rewinding-stdcout-to-go-back-to-the-beginning-of-a-line)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
cout << "\r" << string << endl;
```

`endl` moves the cursor to the next line.  Try replacing it with `std::flush` which just ensures output's sent towards the terminal.  (You should also `#include <iomanip>` and use `std::setw(2)` / `std::setfill('0')` to ensure the text you display is constant width, otherwise say the time moves from:

```
23:59:59
```

to

```
0:0:0
```

The trailing ":59" from the earlier time is not currently being overwritten or cleared (you could write a few spaces or send a clear-to-end-of-line character sequence if your terminal has one, but fixed-width makes more sense).

So ultimately:

```
std::cout << '\r'
          << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << h << ':'
          << std::setw(2) << m << ':'
          << std::setw(2) << s << std::flush;
```

Comment: for some reason it is telling me `no matching function for call to 'fill(char)'`

Comment: I think it is supposed to be `setFill('0')`

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
cout << "\r" << string;
```

`endl` inserts a new-line character and flushes the stream.

Comment: This gives me a compiler error "std::string" illegal use of this type expression.

Comment: @Fuujin What's the compiler? It seems to be fine with [gcc](https://wandbox.org/permlink/8a5958JsraUWbIcy).

Answer (score 3):

`endl` inserts a new-line character and flushes the stream.

```
cout << "\r" << string ; //works
```

Answer (score 1):

I want to provide some useful information first.

You are inserting `std::endl` which prints next string on the next line.

`std::endl` is a newline `\n` followed by `std::flush`

The following newline `\n` and `std::flush` is equivalent to `std::endl`.

```
std::cout << printFunction() << '\n' << std::flush;
```

is just like

```
std::cout << printFunction() << std::endl;
```

Now removing `std::endl` will print the string in the same line.

```
cout << "\r" << string;
```